# export matplotlib setup 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, python-3.6, fedora-25

I have moved to Fedora 25 to Fedora 26(Linux, just for the information). In the process there are some changes in `matplotlib` as well.

In Fedora 25:

- python3-3.5.3-4.fc25.x86_64
- python3-matplotlib-1.5.2-0.2.rc2.fc25.x86_64
- [image]

In Fedora 26:

- python3-3.6.0-22.fc26.x86_64
- python3-matplotlib-2.0.0-2.fc26.2.x86_64
- [image]

The code to create these two image is same (just copied from one machine to another.). You can see that

- colors have changed
- label's font is bigger in matplotlib-2
- tics are outside (I know how to change it)
- there is no tics in top and right (I don't know how to change it in matplotlibrc)
- worst of all, spaces between points has changed (tight is tighter now)

I understand those changes are due to [changes in matplotlib style](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html).
Is there any way to export all the configurations from matplotlib 1.5 to matplotlib-2, which will yield exact figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
mpl.style.use('classic')
```

at the top.

This is mentioned at the official site [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html) (within the introduction)

(Of course you could also downgrade your matplotlib. The question then is if there is a ready binary in fedora's packages or if you would need pip install; on a linux system, the latter should not hurt too much in terms of install-pain)